# Preventing x86 compilers from emitting specific instructions

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, x86, clang, x86-64

I have some application that can parse several x86 instructions but not the whole possible instruction set. Therefore, to generate input for this application, I need a compiler where I can specify which instructions are allowed or not allowed to be emitted by the compiler.

Is there some x86 compiler which gives the user the opportunity to exclude some parts of the instruction set?

Comment: What are those "several x86 instructions"? Do they fit into [i686, core2, presscott...](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html)? Use `-march` to select the appropriate set

Comment: I thought about a more fine grained solution for single instructions

Comment: You can simply remove the instruction definitions from the .td files in LLVM (and make sure those instructions are not generated directly by some passes).

Comment: Did you ever try that? Doesn't some passes or optimizations rely on having certain instructions available?

Comment: Most optimization passes happen on an internal representation, before final code-gen.  However, I could imagine you might get terrible code if some expected instructions are missing.  What kind of instructions does your code not support?  Rarely-used stuff like [`xadd`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XADD.html), or do you mean something like `LEA`?

Comment: I need to avoid more exotic instructions like for example "LDMXCSR". LEA/MOV/PUSH/POP... etc. are supported.

Comment: Then it should be fairly safe to do. X86 backend passes do not rely on any of the less common instructions. You can disable all of the MMX*, SSE* and AVX* instructions, there is even no need to edit .td files, you can do that with subtargets.

Comment: That sounds as exactly as what I need. You could make an answer for that. Can you describe maybe for a single instruction how to exclude it? I don't really know how to use "subtargets" in llvm.